# Fortran compilation using Makefile - Solving a dependency issue

Tags: makefile, module, compilation, dependencies, fortran

I tried to use the following Makefile to compile a Fortran program that I wrote (AltitudeCalculator.f90), which uses another Fortran module (COESA_module contained in COESA.f90) as dependency:

The folder structure of my project is as such:

```
Project/
├── src/
│   ├── COESA.f90
│   ├── AltitudeCalculator.f90
├── include/
├── build/
├── bin/
├── Makefile
```

and here is my current iteration of the Makefile:

```
# Compiler settings
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
DEPFLAGS = -MMD -MP
INCLUDE = -Iinclude

# Directories
SRCDIR = ./src
BUILDDIR = ./build
BINDIR = ./bin

# Source files
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.f90)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.f90,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
EXECUTABLE = $(BINDIR)/AltitudeCalculator
$(info EXECUTABLE is $(EXECUTABLE))

# Generate dependency files
DEPFILES = $(SRCS:.f90=.d)
$(info DEPENDENCY FILES are $(DEPFILES))
-include $(DEPFILES)

# Dependencies
#DEPS = $(filter-out $(BUILDDIR)/AltitudeCalculator.mod,$(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.f90,$(BUILDDIR)/%.mod,$(SRCS)))
DEPS = $(BUILDDIR)/COESA.mod $(BUILDDIR)/coesa_module.mod $(BUILDDIR)/AltitudeCalculator.mod
$(info DEPENDENCIES are $(DEPS))

# Targets
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(info Building executable: $@)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $(OBJS)

#$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90 $(DEPS)
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90 $(DEPS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(info Compiling: $<)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.mod: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(info Generating module: $@)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -J$(BUILDDIR) -c $< -o $@
    @cp $@ .

clean:
    $(info Cleaning up...)
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/* $(BINDIR)/* ./*.mod

.PHONY: all clean
```

Upon compiling the code using this Makefile, I get the following error message:

```
EXECUTABLE is ./bin/AltitudeCalculator
DEPENDENCY FILES are ./src/AltitudeCalculator.d ./src/COESA.d
DEPENDENCIES are ./build/COESA.mod ./build/coesa_module.mod ./build/AltitudeCalculator.mod
Generating module: build/COESA.mod
gfortran -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -J./build -c src/COESA.f90 -o build/COESA.mod
Generating module: build/AltitudeCalculator.mod
gfortran -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -J./build -c src/AltitudeCalculator.f90 -o build/AltitudeCalculator.mod
Compiling: src/AltitudeCalculator.f90
gfortran -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Iinclude -c src/AltitudeCalculator.f90 -o build/AltitudeCalculator.o
src/AltitudeCalculator.f90:3:8:

    3 |     use COESA_module, only: State, COESA_atmosphere
      |        1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘coesa_module.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:41: build/AltitudeCalculator.o] Error 1
```

and my folder structure now looks like this:

```
Project/
    ├── src/
    │   ├── COESA.f90
    │   ├── AltitudeCalculator.f90
    ├── include/
    ├── build/
    │   ├── AltitudeCalculator.mod
    │   ├── COESA.mod
    │   ├── coesa_module.mod
    ├── bin/
    ├── Makefile
    ├── AltitudeCalculator.mod
    ├── COESA.mod
```

When I manually copy coesa_module.mod into the current directory (at the same level as the Makefile), the compilation works. But I have to compile twice, and it doesn't seem to be a clean process. I tried to use the line

```
@cp $@ .
```

to copy all the modules into the working directory but for an unknown reason, coesa_module.mod couldn't be copied.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Writing manual Makefiles for Fortran in this day and age is an exercise in futility. It can be done, sure. But it will make you to think twice about any change in the codebase that would require a change in the Makefile and can lead to big long sourcefiles with thousands of lines (true story that still leaves traces in my code even after more than 10 years of using automation).

Comment: 100% agree with @VladimirFГероямслава , use something like Cmake or meson (my preference). But why are you compiling AltitudeCalculator twice?

Comment: Thanks for your answers @VladimirFГероямслава & Ian Bush. That's the first time in ages since I've last done any Fortran work and it seems I was trying to bite off something bigger than I can chew. In university, we would create Makefiles manually but I don't know how to generate one with Cmake. And to answer your question Ian: precisely, I don't really understand why AltitudeCalculator.f90 was compiled twice and why I need the module in the main directory to build the executable.
Could you tell me how I can create a working Makefile with Cmake?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the "$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90 $(DEPS)" line creates the object files and the "$(BUILDDIR)/%.mod: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90" only creates the modules, right? If I'm removing the cp command, I'll first generate all the .mod files in the BUILDDIR and the .o files will also be created in there. The problem is that I need to copy coesa_module.mod into the directory where the Makefile is located to generate the object files, else the compilation breaks since coesa_module.mod is required for building AltitudeCalculator.o (but why doesn't it fetch the module in the builddir?)

Answer (score 2):

Just to very simply answer the question you asked, "why isn't the `coesa_module.mod` file copied?" and it's because this rule:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.mod: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(info Generating module: $@)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -J$(BUILDDIR) -c $< -o $@
        @cp $@ .
```

says how to build a `./build/XXX.mod` file from a `./src/XXX.f90` file then copy it to `.`, for any string `XXX`.

But this rule cannot match `coesa_module.mod` because you don't have a `coesa_module.f90` file, so the `XXX` in this case (`coesa_module`) doesn't match this rule.  Since it doesn't match this rule, make won't use this rule to build it.  Because make doesn't use this rule, it doesn't copy the file (obviously).

You can see from the output you show that make doesn't invoke ANY recipe to "build" the target `coesa_module.mod` (i.e., you have no output saying `Generating module: coesa_module.mod`) which is just as expected since there's no rule in the makefile that will build it, based on the content of your `src` directory.